# How to create a QClass , without an entity or associated with two tables in QueryDSL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, querydsl

let's say that I have three classes

```
    @Entity
    public class Book {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        @Column
        private String name;
    }

    @Entity
    public class Author {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        @Column
        private String fistName;

        @Column
        private String lastName;
    }

    @Entity
    public class AuthorBookRelation {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "author", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private Author author;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "book", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private Book book;
    }
```

And accordingly, I have three Qclasses

QAuthor QBook QAuthorBookRelation.

but I can do just two classes.

```
@Entity
    public class Book {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        @Column
        private String name;
    }

    @Entity
    public class Author {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        @Column
        private String fistName;

        @Column
        private String lastName;

        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(
                name = "author_book_relation",
                joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "author")},
                inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "book")}
        )
        private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Then there is not need for class AuthorBookRelation.
But i need QAuthorBookRelation to create a request with queryDSL

How to create a class that is bound to two tables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing the point of JPA, JPQL and QueryDSL. You should join associated entities. There is absolutely no need for association entities in any of these technologies, unless you need to associate data with this association.

Otherwise, you'd just do:

```java
List<Tuple> result = query().from(QBook.book)
     .innerJoin(QBook.book.author, author)
     .select(QBook.book, QAuthor.author)
     .fetch();
```

Which is equivalent to the following JPQL:

```sql
SELECT book, author FROM Book book INNER JOIN book.author author
```

Comment: Theres no point in generating QClasses for associations because they cant be represented in JPQL, the query language for JPA.